# How can i use the result of one function, as an argument of another function?

Tags: python, function, variables, arguments, global

It somewhat works like this. It's just a block of the main code. `x`, `y` are properly defined

```
def  Function_1 (x,y):
    global zone
    # there are some conditions which get the value of variable zone
    return zone

def Function_2 (zone):
    #then there are some conditions wherein i use variable zone

Function_2 (zone)
```

So the the error is "zone not defined" in the line 32
Sorry for asking a silly question but i am new and i need desperately need help

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ why do u think it isn't a code

Comment: It wasn't code until you fixed it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ sorry for disturbing but can you please help me out

Comment: Double check what is going on line 32 - the error message indicates you are using zone before it is assigned to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal! First of all, you need to assign your variable before to use it. The line `global zone` allows python to know that `zone` variable exists and not created a local variable in the function. If the word `global` is missing, python creates another variable (local) with the same name but different adresses.

```
zone = None
def  Function_1 (x,y):
  global zone
  #there are some conditions which get the value of variable zone
  return zone

def Function_2 (zone):
  #then there are some conditions wherein i use variable zone

Function_2 (zone)
```

In looking your code, we see function named Function_1 returns zone.

- Is that necessary to use `zone` as global variable?
- You can re-use the result `Function_1` like argument of Function_2. Something like this: `Function_2 (Function_1 (x,y))`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run `Function_2`, when `Function_1` hasn't been called. The easiest way to fix this is to run `Function_2` on the results of `Function_1` like this:

```
def  Function_1 (x,y):
    global zone
    #there are some conditions which get the value of variable zone
    return zone
def Function_2 (zone):
    #then there are some conditions wherein i use variable zone
Function_2(Function_1(1,2))
```

When you call `Function_1(1,2)`, `Function_1(1,2)` becomes equal to what the function returned, so you are just setting `zone` which is a parameter of `Function_2` to the return of `Function_1(1,2)`.

Also, you said x, and y are defined. You can't set the value of a variable and use it with the function, you need to pass it in. For Example:

```
x=1
def Function (x):
    return x
Function()
```

This doesn't work you need to pass in `x` when you call it like this:

```
def Function (x):
    return x
Function(1)
```

This would set `x` to `1`

It seems you don't know a lot about how functions work, try reading [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Functions) guide.